# Laravel/Homestead vagrant machine issues when trying to access hosts

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

I have a very simple setup:

- Windows 10
- VirtualBox 6.0
- Vagrant 2.2.2
- Vagrant Host Updater plugin (to automatically set hosts from Vagrantfile)
- Laravel/Homestead 7 vagrant box

When I create this box (laravel/homestead-7), it has no errors. When I provision the box - no errors as well. I can even SSH into the box and access properly mapped folders between host/guest machines. But I have a problem with accessing the hosts: the hosts are automatically set with vagrant plugin upon running the machine, the problem is that those hosts are unreachable when trying to access it through browser or pinging from cmd (ex: ping homestead - returns General failure error. But I can ssh without no problem). The funny thing is - that sometimes it works properly without changing anything, but most of the time it is untrustworthy and when I need to do my work quickly - this becomes tedious. Also to note - I can share my environment from the inside the box with ngrok service which then allows me to use public URL to access my projects (which shows that the apache service inside the box is working properly or am I mistaken?).

I also have NordVPN, not sure if additional network drivers from this service might have caused this? Furthermore I have BitDefender as an antivirus/firewall, but I've made sure to add virtualbox headless, vagrant to the exception lists, also disabled hosts from being scanned/managed by the antivirus.

Could please someone help me with this? If anyone could give me atleast a tip where to start - I would be really thankful.

[Pinging homestead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7Lm7.png)
[Hosts file entry from vagrant hosts plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdYqe.png)
[Console output when starting the machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOjOh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a similar configuration.

My solution was to go into the VPN and make sure local IP addresses can bypass the VPN. You have to find a way to filter out localhost. Similar issues could be caused by antivirus or Windows Defender, depending on how aggressive they are set up.

Before I found a way to allow local IP addresses, using a terminal I would ping the Homestead IP of 192.168.10.10 and it would return General Failure.

After I updated the IP filtering from my VPN and allowed local IP addresses to stay local, the ping worked again and the VHs resolved as expected.